# Update Muitos para Muitos Entity Framework c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, crud

Bom dia,

Estou com dificuldades para atualizar um registro com entityframework, vou informar toda a estrutura abaixo.
Resumindo, tenho um cadastro de artistas, onde estes artistas estão relacionados a endereço e a categorias.

Um artista pode ter um endereço (um pra um), e artistas pode ter muitas categorias (muitos pra muitos).

entidades:

Artista: 
relacionamento um pra um com endereco
relacionamento muitos para muitos com categorias

```
public class Artista
    {

        public Artista()
        {
            ArtistaCategoria = new List<ArtistaCategoria>();
        }

        public int ArtistaId { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Site { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }

        public virtual Endereco Endereco { get; set; }

        public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataAtualizacao { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ArtistaCategoria> ArtistaCategoria { get; set; }
    }

public class Categoria
    {
        public Categoria()
        {
        }

        public int CategoriaId { get; set; }

        public string Nome { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ArtistaCategoria> ArtistaCategoria { get; set; }
    }

public class Endereco
    {

        public Endereco()
        {
            Municipio = new Municipio();
        }
        public int EnderecoId { get; set; }
        public string Logradouro { get; set; }
        public string Numero { get; set; }
        public string Bairro { get; set; }
        public string Cep { get; set; }
        public int MunicipioId { get; set; }
        public virtual Municipio Municipio { get; set; }

    }

public class Municipio
    {
        public Municipio()
        {
        }

        public int MunicipioId { get; set; }

        public string Nome { get; set; }

        public string Cep { get; set; }

    }
```

Configuração Fluent API

```
public class ArtistaConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Artista>
    {
        public ArtistaConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(a => a.ArtistaId);

            Property(a => a.Nome)
                .IsRequired();

            Property(a => a.Email)
                .HasMaxLength(150);

        }


public class EnderecoConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Endereco>
    {
        public EnderecoConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(x => x.EnderecoId);
            Property(x => x.Logradouro).IsRequired();
            HasRequired(m => m.Municipio)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(m => m.MunicipioId);

            Property(m => m.Cep)
                .IsFixedLength()
                .HasMaxLength(9)
                .HasColumnType("char");

        }
    }
```

Não estou conseguindo editar os dados, quando vou salvar as categorias, é mostrado um erro informando que o MunicipioId é inválido.

Sempre trabalhei com ADO e Stored Procedures, e sempre ouvi muita gente falando que isso é um atrazo, que com Entity é muito mais rápido e fácil, mas sinceramente estou achando que perdi o controle, com SPs você tem a aplicação na mão, qualquer erro é facil de identificar.

Neste caso, ao editar o relacionamento da categoria e do artista, gera-se um erro no municipio (artista > endereco > municipio), sinceramente não consigo identificar o problema.

Segue o código do update:

```
public void Update(Artista obj, string[] arrayCategoria)
        {
            AtualizaEndereco(obj);
            ValidaCategorias(obj, arrayCategoria);
            Db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
            Db.SaveChanges();
        }

private void AtualizaEndereco(Artista artista)
        {
            var endereco = artista.Endereco;
            endereco.Municipio = null;
            Db.Entry(endereco).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }


private void AtualizarCategorias(Artista artista, string[] categorias)
    {
        var artistaAtual = Db.Artistas
            .FirstOrDefault(a => a.ArtistaId == artista.ArtistaId);
        //todo: fazer lista de categoria de acordo com array recebido
        List<Categoria> categoriasSelecionadas = new List<Categoria>();

        if (categorias != null)
        {
            foreach (var cat in categorias)
            {
                categoriasSelecionadas.Add(Db.Categorias.Find(int.Parse(cat)));
            }
        }

        foreach (var categoria in categoriasSelecionadas)
        {
            var artistaCategoria = new ArtistaCategoria
            {
                Artista = artistaAtual,
                Categoria = categoria
            };

            Db.ArtistaCategoria.Add(artistaCategoria);
            Db.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
```

Código do controller que edita o cadastro:

```
public class ArtistaController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IArtistaAppService _artistaApp;
        private readonly IMunicipioAppService _municipioApp;
        private readonly ICategoriaAppService _categoriaApp;
        public ArtistaController(IArtistaAppService artistaApp, IMunicipioAppService municipioApp, ICategoriaAppService categoriaApp)
        {
            _artistaApp = artistaApp;
            _municipioApp = municipioApp;
            _categoriaApp = categoriaApp;
        }
[...]

[HttpPost]
        [ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult Edit(ArtistaViewModel artista, string[] arrayCategoria)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                var artistaDomain = Mapper.Map<ArtistaViewModel, Artista>(artista);
                _artistaApp.Update(artistaDomain, arrayCategoria);

                return RedirectToAction("index");
            }

            return View(artista);
        }


@model ViewModels.ArtistaViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default" data-collapsed="0">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="panel-title">
                            Dados do cadastro<br />
                        </div>

                        <div class="panel-options">
                            <a href="#" data-rel="collapse"><i class="entypo-down-open"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ArtistaId)

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                <button class="btn btn-blue btn-icon" type="button" id='addButton'>Adicionar telefone<i class="entypo-phone"></i></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Endereco.Cep, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Endereco.Cep, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Endereco.Logradouro, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Endereco.Logradouro, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Endereco.Numero, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Endereco.Numero, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Endereco.Bairro, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Endereco.Bairro, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Endereco.MunicipioId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <select id="Endereco_MunicipioId" name="Endereco.MunicipioId" class="form-control"></select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Endereco.EnderecoId)

                        @{

                            List<ViewModels.CategoriasSelecionadas> categorias = ViewBag.Categorias;

                            foreach (var categoria in categorias)
                            {

                                <input type="checkbox"
                                       name="arrayCategoria"
                                       value="@categoria.CategoriaId"
                                       @(Html.Raw(categoria.Selecionada ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")) />
                                    @categoria.CategoriaId @:  @categoria.Nome


                            }
                        }

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group default-padding">
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-icon" type="submit">Salvar<i class="entypo-check"></i></button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-icon btn-default">Cancelar alterações <i class="entypo-cancel"></i></button>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index")" class="btn btn-icon btn-info">Voltar para listagem<i class="entypo-reply"></i></a>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Update many to many Entity Framework c#](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/112941/update-many-to-many-entity-framework-c)

Comment: De novo a mesma perguntas ?

Comment: Na verdade são parecidas, uma foi criada com base nas respostas dada pelo cigano, para continuar o raciocínio, refiz a pergunta aplicando as alterações indicadas...

Answer (score 4):

Este é o jeito difícil de fazer. Essa configuração da Fluent API já foi superada há tempos.

Defina sua entidade associativa manualmente:

```
public class ArtistaCategoria
{
    [Key]
    public int ArtistaCategoriaId { get; set; }
    [Index("IUQ_ArtistaCategoria_ArtistaId_CategoriaId", IsUnique = true, Order = 1)]
    public int ArtistaId { get; set; }
    [Index("IUQ_ArtistaCategoria_ArtistaId_CategoriaId", IsUnique = true, Order = 2)]
    public int CategoriaId { get; set; }

    public virtual Artista Artista { get; set; }
    public virtual Categoria Categoria { get; set; }
}
```

[`[Index]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.indexattribute(v=vs.113).aspx), introduzido nesta forma a partir do Entity Framework 6.1.0, garante a unicidade do registro associativo. Validações adicionais podem ser necessárias na aplicação para evitar erros estranhos de duplicidade de chave para o usuário.

Altere também seus *Models* para o seguinte:

```
public class Artista
{
    [Key]
    public int ArtistaId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Site { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    public virtual Endereco Endereco { get; set; }

    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataAtualizacao { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ArtistaCategoria> ArtistaCategorias { get; set; }
}

public class Categoria
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoriaId { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ArtistaCategoria> ArtistaCategorias { get; set; }
}
```

Com isso, você não precisa usar a configuração da Fluent API.

O código abaixo basta para criar as relações entre artistas e categorias:

```
var artistaAtual = Db.Artistas
            .FirstOrDefault(a => a.ArtistaId == artista.ArtistaId);
var tresCategorias = Db.Categorias.Take(3).ToList();

foreach (var categoria in tresCategorias)
{
    var artistaCategoria = new ArtistaCategoria
    {
        Artista = artistaAtual,
        Categoria = categoria
    };

    Db.ArtistaCategorias.Add(artistaCategoria);
    Db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Valew Cigano, vou testar e posto aqui o resultado, assim parece bem mais simples mesmo.

Comment: Ainda está gerando erro no Db.SaveChanges(); sou informado que o Endereço não pode ser nulo.

Comment: Ah, sim. Veja que o exemplo que coloquei não contempla as demais validações que você precisa fazer. Possivelmente vai ter que inserir endereços de exemplo, e assim por diante.

Comment: por isso que digo que não tenho controle, eu não estou cadastrando endereço, estou editando o cadastro, o endereço já existe, e ele gera um erro qnd uso o Db.SaveChanges() após adicionar ou remover uma categoria.. mas a categoria não tem relação com endereço..

Comment: O endereço viria da View preenchido? Isto seria outra pergunta.

Comment: sim, vem da view, mas tem caso que não será informado, ele deverá ser nulo mesmo.. quando ignoro as categorias eu consigo editar tudo normal, com ou sem endereço, mas qnd vou editar as categorias gera esse erro..

Comment: Bom, vamos para outra pergunta. Aí você coloca lá como está a tela atualmente e o erro específico.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35185/discussion-between-alexandre-previatti-and-cigano-morrison-mendez).