# Update many to many Entity Framework c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, crud

Estou com dificuldades para atualizar um registro com entityframework, vou informar toda a estrutura abaixo.
Resumindo, tenho um cadastro de artistas, onde estes artistas estão relacionados a categorias.

entidades:

Artista: 
relacionamento um pra um com endereco
relacionamento muitos para muitos com categorias

```
public class Artista
    {

        public int ArtistaId { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Site { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }

        public virtual Endereco Endereco { get; set; }

        public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataAtualizacao { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ArtistaCategoria> ArtistaCategoria { get; set; }
    }

public class Categoria
    {
        public Categoria()
        {
        }

        public int CategoriaId { get; set; }

        public string Nome { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ArtistaCategoria> ArtistaCategoria { get; set; }
    }

public class ArtistaCategoria
    {
        public int ArtistaCategoriaId { get; set; }
        public int ArtistaId { get; set; }
        public int CategoriaId { get; set; }

        public virtual Artista Artista { get; set; }
        public virtual Categoria Categoria { get; set; }
    }

public class Endereco
    {

        public Endereco()
        {
            Municipio = new Municipio();
        }
        public int EnderecoId { get; set; }
        public string Logradouro { get; set; }
        public string Numero { get; set; }
        public string Bairro { get; set; }
        public string Cep { get; set; }
        public int MunicipioId { get; set; }
        public virtual Municipio Municipio { get; set; }

    }

public class Municipio
    {
        public Municipio()
        {
        }

        public int MunicipioId { get; set; }

        public string Nome { get; set; }

        public string Cep { get; set; }

    }
```

Configuração Fluent API

```
public class ArtistaConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Artista>
    {
        public ArtistaConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(a => a.ArtistaId);

            Property(a => a.Nome)
                .IsRequired();

            Property(a => a.Email)
                .HasMaxLength(150);

        }


public class EnderecoConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Endereco>
    {
        public EnderecoConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(x => x.EnderecoId);
            HasRequired(m => m.Municipio)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(m => m.MunicipioId);

            Property(m => m.Cep)
                .IsFixedLength()
                .HasMaxLength(9)
                .HasColumnType("char");

        }
    }
```

Ao editar o relacionamento da categoria e do artista, gera-se um erro.

> Attaching an entity of type 'ShowFacil.Domain.Entities.Artista' failed
>   because another entity of the same type already has the same primary
>   key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting
>   the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in
>   the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some
>   entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key
>   values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state
>   to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to
>   'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

Segue o código do update:

```
public void Update(Artista obj, string[] arrayCategoria)
        {
            AtualizaEndereco(obj);
            ValidaCategorias(obj, arrayCategoria);
            Db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified; << ERRO ACONTECE AQUI
            Db.SaveChanges();
        }

private void AtualizaEndereco(Artista artista)
    {

        if (artista.Endereco != null)
        {
            var endereco = artista.Endereco;

            if (artista.Endereco.MunicipioId != 0)
            {
                var municipio = Db.Municipios.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MunicipioId == artista.Endereco.MunicipioId);
                endereco.Municipio = municipio;

                if (endereco.EnderecoId != 0)
                {
                    Db.Entry(endereco).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
                else
                {
                    Db.Enderecos.Add(endereco);
                }

                artista.Endereco = endereco;
            }

        }

    }


    private void AtualizarCategorias(Artista artista, string[] categorias)
        {
            var artistaAtual = Db.Artistas
                .FirstOrDefault(a => a.ArtistaId == artista.ArtistaId);

            List<Categoria> categoriasSelecionadas = new List<Categoria>();
            if (categorias != null)
            {
                foreach (var cat in categorias)
                {
                    categoriasSelecionadas.Add(Db.Categorias.Find(int.Parse(cat)));
                }
            }
var categoriasOriginais = Db.ArtistaCategoria.Where(at => at.ArtistaId == artista.ArtistaId).ToList();
            foreach (var item in categoriasOriginais)
            {
                Db.ArtistaCategoria.Remove(item);
                Db.SaveChanges();
            }

            foreach (var categoria in categoriasSelecionadas)
            {
                var artistaCategoria = new ArtistaCategoria
                {
                    Artista = artistaAtual,
                    Categoria = categoria
                };

                Db.ArtistaCategoria.Add(artistaCategoria);
                Db.SaveChanges();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Este erro é bem comum, sobretudo justamente porque você está aprendendo Entity Framework agora.

Ao fazer isto:

```
var artistaAtual = Db.Artistas
            .FirstOrDefault(a => a.ArtistaId == artista.ArtistaId);
```

Você está carregando o mesmo artista duas vezes. Como uma coleção observável, o Entity Framework se perde ao definir unicamente a entrada a ser atualizada.

Para evitar isso, use `AsNoTracking()`, indicando ao Entity Framework que ele não deve observar a segunda coleção, assim:

```
var artistaAtual = Db.Artistas.AsNoTracking()
            .FirstOrDefault(a => a.ArtistaId == artista.ArtistaId);
```

Como você está usando um artista destacado do contexto, isto obviamente não pode ser usado, ou o contexto vai achar que `artistaAtual` é um artista novo, justamente porque não está observando este registro:

```
            var artistaCategoria = new ArtistaCategoria
            {
                Artista = artistaAtual,
                Categoria = categoria
            };
```

Troque para:

```
            var artistaCategoria = new ArtistaCategoria
            {
                Artista = artista,
                Categoria = categoria
            };
```

Pode ser necessário avisar o contexto que o objeto existe e deve ser observado:

```
Db.Artistas.Attach(artista);
```

Portanto:

```
    public void Update(Artista obj, string[] arrayCategoria)
    {
        Db.Artistas.Attach(artista);
        AtualizaEndereco(obj);
        ValidaCategorias(obj, arrayCategoria);
        Db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
        Db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Ok, não gerou erro, porém agora sempre cadastra um novo artista..

Comment: Porque você está usando `Add`. `Add` sempre adiciona um novo artista. Deixe para chamar a troca de `State` fora do método de validação das categorias.

Comment: não entendi... Deixe para chamar a troca de State fora do método de validação das categorias.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Continua adicionando um novo artista...

Comment: Sabe me dizer depois de qual `SaveChanges` ocorre essa inserção duplicada?

Comment: Do saveChanges após var artistaCategoria = new ArtistaCategoria
            {
                Artista = artista,
                Categoria = categoria
            };

Comment: Atualizei mais uma vez.